# More on casting Func<T,T> and Expression<Func<T,T>>

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda, expression-trees

I've spent hours with this but haven't managed...

Please see example below - How can this be done?

The idea is to build a compiled expression of type `Func<dynamic, dynamic>` given an `Expression<Func<T1,T2>>` passed by the class' consumer. I have been able to solve this problem (thanks to SO) IF the types T1 and T2 are known at design time. But I'm looking for a solution for the case in which T1 and T2 are NOT known at design time.

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

```
public class ExpressionExample
{
    private Func<dynamic, dynamic> _compiledExpression;

    public ExpressionExample(LambdaExpression lambdaExpression)
    {
        // How does one get a compiled expression of type
        // Func<dynamic, dynamic> at this point given lambdaExpression?
    }
}
```

Comment: lambdaExpression is supposed to be of type Expression<Func<T1, T2>> and we want to extract a delegate of type Func<dynamic, dynamic> (my original text is not being displayed correctly).

Comment: Are you using `dynamic` to indicate C# 4.0 `dynamic` or just in the general sense of the word "dynamic"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm not understanding your question, this should work:

```
public class ExpressionExample<T1, T2>
{
    private Func<dynamic, dynamic> _compiledExpression;

    public ExpressionExample(
        Expression<Func<T1, T2>> lambdaExpression)
    {
        // How does one get a compiled expression of type
        // Func<dynamic, dynamic> at this point given lambdaExpression?
        var func = lambdaExpression.Compile();
        _compiledExpression = (dynamic x) => (dynamic)func((T1)x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that he doesn't want to change the function's signature.  If he can, this is the best solution.

Comment: Hi guys, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it. I can't believe I spent so much time with this to not even come close to the solution. But well, I learnt quite a lot along the way too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call `Compile` on the `LambdaExpression`, then build and compile another expression tree that calls the delegate using `Expression.Invoke(Expression, params Expression)`.

Comment: The problem is the second tree needs to include type conversions, otherwise the call to the delegate fails; I don't know the types at design time and the compiler tells me that it can not "infer those from usage"...

Comment: You need to build the tree at runtime.  You might also need to call `Expression.Convert`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in to something similar myself. Being a newbie I won't attempt to answer your question in full but maybe you can find the answer from the answer given to me from forums.asp.net which I also posted right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031547/a-general-validation-attribute-for-checking-uniqueness-in-a-linq-to-sql-data-cont/2035658#2035658) on stackoverflow.